# Angular.js integration with the in-browser RAML parser

Tags: angularjs, rest, raml

I've make quite a lot of use of the $http module in Angular in various services but was wanting to integrate it with Mulesofts RAML parser. This would give me the advantage of not having to update some parts of angular in order to fit the RAML spec.

Has anyone done this? What are the required steps?

If this is not possible I guess its not too much work to just use the $resource module for the REST resources described in RAML.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible to integrate any library into AngularJS.

It's even simpler in your case - the RAML module returns promises which Angular will consume into its own promises using `$q.when` which takes care of the entire digest cycle integration problem for you for free.

The RAML parser is used like:

```
//example from the documentation
RAML.Parser.loadFile('http://localhost:9001/myAPI.raml').then( function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}, function(error) {
  console.log('Error parsing: ' + error);
});
```

All you need to do for it to play nicely with Angular is wrap that with `$q.when` which takes care of integration into the digest cycle:

```
$.when(RAML.Parser.loadFile('http://localhost:9001/myAPI.raml')).then( function(data) {
  $scope.someProp = data;
}).catch(function(error) {
  throw error; //Angular promises log when you use throw instead of $q.reject
});
```

Of course, for clean Angular code - you should extract it into a service.

The key is that both the RAML module and Angular use a Promises/A+ complaint implementation of promises so it is *extremely* simple to integrate the two. RAML uses `Q` and Angular uses a touched down version of it called $q.

Comment: thanks but there doesn't appear to be anything in the wiki right now for the parser. I will take a look at the api-designer to see how they are generating code (the code that generates the API tests from raml)